# Multiple Leader for term In Raft Implementation

Tags: go, distributed-system, consensus, raft

I'm Implementing a basic Raft Consensus Algorithm. But while electing a leader some time get multiple leader for a single Term Here is my Implementation for raft Election

```
//RequestVote Rpc Handler
func (rf *Raft) RequestVote(args *RequestVoteArgs, reply *RequestVoteReply) {
    rf.mu.Lock()
    defer rf.mu.Unlock()
    reply.Term = args.Term
    if rf.currentTerm >= args.Term {
        reply.VoteGranted = false
        return
    }
    if true {
        rf.convertToFollower(args.Term, args.CandidateId)
        DPrintf("term:%v, %v voted %v", args.Term, rf.me, args.CandidateId)
        reply.VoteGranted = true
        return
    }
    reply.VoteGranted = false
}

//AppendEntry(Heartbeat) Rpc handler
func (rf *Raft) AppendEntry(args *AppendEntryArgs, reply *AppendEntryReply) {
    rf.mu.Lock()
    defer rf.mu.Unlock()
    reply.Term = args.Term
    if args.Term < rf.currentTerm {
        reply.Success = false
        return
    }
    if true {
        if (args.Term > rf.currentTerm) || (args.Term == rf.currentTerm && rf.state == candidate) {
            rf.convertToFollower(args.Term, args.LeaderId)
        }
        rf.lastAppendEntryTime = time.Now()
        reply.Success = true
        return
    }
    reply.Success = false

}

func (rf *Raft) sendRequestVote(server int, args *RequestVoteArgs, reply *RequestVoteReply) bool {
    ok := rf.peers[server].Call("Raft.RequestVote", args, reply)
    return ok
}

func (rf *Raft) sendAppendEntry(server int, args *AppendEntryArgs, reply *AppendEntryReply) bool {
    ok := rf.peers[server].Call("Raft.AppendEntry", args, reply)
    return ok
}


//Electing a new leader 
func (rf *Raft) KickStartElection() {

    rf.mu.Lock()
    rf.convertToCandidate()

    term := rf.currentTerm
    candidateId := rf.me
    // lastLogIndex := rf.commitIndex
    // lastLogTerm := rf.log[rf.commitIndex].Term
    rf.mu.Unlock()

    var mu sync.Mutex
    cond := sync.NewCond(&mu)

    peerDone := 1
    peerLength := len(rf.peers)
    majority := peerLength/2 + 1
    vote := 1
    var votefrom []int
    // DPrintf("%v,%v:length of peers %v and majority needed %v", rf.me, rf.currentTerm, peerLength, majority)
    for peer := range rf.peers {
        if peer == rf.me {
            continue
        }
        go func(peer int) {
            args := RequestVoteArgs{Term: term, CandidateId: candidateId}
            reply := RequestVoteReply{}
            rf.sendRequestVote(peer, &args, &reply)
            mu.Lock()
            peerDone++
            if reply.VoteGranted {
                // DPrintf("term %v:%v me,%v peer", rf.currentTerm, rf.me, peer)
                vote++
                votefrom = append(votefrom, peer)
            }
            cond.Broadcast()
            mu.Unlock()
        }(peer)
    }

    mu.Lock()
    for {
        rf.mu.Lock()
        if rf.state != candidate {
            rf.mu.Unlock()
            break
        } else {
            rf.mu.Unlock()
        }
        if (peerLength - peerDone) < (majority - vote) {
            break
        }
        if vote >= majority {
            // DPrintf("%v leader, term %v", rf.me, rf.currentTerm)
            DPrintf("term:%v,leader:%v,%v", term, rf.me, votefrom)
            rf.convertToLeader()
            break
        }
        cond.Wait()
    }
    mu.Unlock()

}

func (rf *Raft) convertToCandidate() {
    rf.currentTerm++
    rf.state = candidate
    rf.votedFor = rf.me
}

func (rf *Raft) convertToLeader() {
    rf.mu.Lock()
    rf.state = leader
    rf.mu.Unlock()
    rf.sendEntry()
}

func (rf *Raft) convertToFollower(term int, CandidateId int) {
    rf.state = follower
    rf.currentTerm = term
    rf.votedFor = CandidateId
}
```

logs for Multiple leader for term Is

```
Test (2A): multiple elections ...
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:22,leader:4,[5 6 2]
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:23, 5 voted 6
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:23, 4 voted 6
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:23, 2 voted 6
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:23,leader:6,[5 4 2]
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:24, 6 voted 2
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:24, 5 voted 2
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:24, 4 voted 2
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:24,leader:2,[6 5 4]
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:25, 6 voted 4
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:25, 2 voted 4
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:25, 5 voted 4
2023/02/19 00:45:07 term:25,leader:4,[6 2 5]
--- FAIL: TestManyElections2A (5.52s)
    config.go:456: term 25 has 2 (>1) leaders [2,4] 

// Raft state at the term of 25
{me: 0, term:11 votedFor:0  state:Candidate}
{me: 1, term:14 votedFor:1  state:Candidate}
{me: 2, term:25 votedFor:4  state:Leader}
{me: 3, term:13 votedFor:3  state:Candidate}
{me: 4, term:25 votedFor:4  state:Leader}
{me: 5, term:25 votedFor:4  state:Follower}
{me: 6, term:25 votedFor:4  state:Follower}
```

As per the raft state prev term leader 2 voted for 4 but not change to follower but In ConvertTofollower raft first changes to follower then update it its term to next term.

Here is Link to complete code
[Raft Implementation](https://github.com/BrolyDBZ/6.824/blob/raft/src/raft/raft.go)

"You may Find config.go and test_test.go helpful"

Answer (score 0):

`reply.Term = args.Term` should be `reply.Term = rf.currentTerm` to let leader/candidate update their term